# Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket

Tags: release-freya

When launching Midori, and several other programs from Terminal, I get the following error:

```
WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-uyN7DFK2Jm: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 5):

Apparently this is an issue with certain programs (such as Midori) leveraging GTK3 extensions. The software funtions normally, and the error can be suppressed by pasting the following into Terminal:

```
export NO_AT_BRIDGE=1
```

I added mine to `/etc/rc.local` and it supressed the errors automatically.

Comment: Would you accept you own answer, I confirm too that it works for me. See https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: I would, but I dont know how... I think that I need more reputation points :(

Comment: No there is no privileges for acceptance even with 1rep. But for self answers, it is allowed only after 48 hours which already passed.